# Nhibernate criteria query inserts an extra order by expression when using JoinType.LeftOuterJoin and Projections

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

Why would this nhibernate criteria query produce the sql query below?

```cs
return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(FundingCategory), "fc")
    .CreateCriteria("FundingPrograms", "fp")
    .CreateCriteria("Projects", "p", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("fp.Recipient.Id", recipientId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("p.Recipient.Id", recipientId))
    )
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("fc.Name"), "fcn")
        .Add(Projections.Sum("fp.ObligatedAmount"), "fpo")
        .Add(Projections.Sum("p.ObligatedAmount"), "po")
    )
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("fpo"))
    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("po"))
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("fcn"))
    .List<object[]>();
```

```sql
SELECT   this_.Name                as y0_,
         sum(fp1_.ObligatedAmount) as y1_,
         sum(p2_.ObligatedAmount)  as y2_
FROM     fundingCategories this_
         inner join fundingPrograms fp1_
           on this_.fundingCategoryId = fp1_.fundingCategoryId
         left outer join projects p2_
           on fp1_.fundingProgramId = p2_.fundingProgramId
WHERE    (fp1_.recipientId = 6 /* @p0 */
           or p2_.recipientId = 6 /* @p1 */)
GROUP BY this_.Name
ORDER BY p2_.name asc,
         y1_ desc,
         y2_ desc,
         y0_ asc
```

It is incorrectly putting the p2_name asc into the ORDER BY statement, and causing it to crash.  This only happens when I use JoinType.LeftOuterJoin on my Projects criteria.  Is this a known nhibernate bug?  I'm using nhibernate 2.0.1.4000.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I'm kind of facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this as a bug on the nh jira forum.

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1761

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but I ran into the same problem.

The ordering was defined in the collection mapping. In your case probably the mapping of the projects in the `FundingPrograms`.
You can't can clear it by calling `.ClearOrders()`

My solution was to add a grouping on the property it tries to sort on, in your case
`.Add(Projections.Group(() => p.name))`